# MS Lightswitch - Getting error message on loading, but unable to find the actual error

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Microsfot Lightswitch, running my deployed applications as Virtual Directory in IIS. So far it is working fine. Since yesterday I am getting the error message right after successful login.

```
The application has stopped responding due to an error and needs to be restarted.
Error details: [Arg_NullReferenceException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.30214.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException
```

I also used fiddler to trace the actual error, but still could not find. Here is the fillder's screen shot:
[image]

Can any body suggest what could be actually going wrong, or how can I reach to the actual real error?

Edit: It seems there is some problem with the read-line in fiddler, but I am unable to dig down the real error, actually I am new to fiddler.

Comment: I would start by trying to troubleshoot that 404 error.  If you click on that row in Fiddler, there should be more details on that error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But could not get any clue. There I checked, it is only showing error message:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

While in details section, the Requested URL = http://localhost:80/Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client;component/screens/screenpresentation/internalframework/resources/resources/x.png

And this is not my application's resource, where could I find it.

Comment: You might try the advice "Enable server diagnostics in your application and check the server trace.axd endpoint to see what happened on the server side." that I found on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6777a81c-b5d6-404e-b76a-adc2e4daf329/argnullreferenceexception-lightswitch-v2?forum=LightSwitchDev11Beta